# SSH Should Be Asking For Password When Authenticating, But Is Not Doing So

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have HPUX 11.31 server that has ssh enabled.  The problem is that when I attempt to
SSH to the server from a client, I am not being challenged during the authentication
process; i.e. the server is not asking me for a password, it simply passes me on through.

I checked the authorized_keys file on the server and it does not contain the key from the client, so there should be not pass-through during the authentication process.

What should I be looking for in order to try to determine what is allowing me to authenticate to the ssh server without being password-challenged?

Thanks ahead of time for any and all responses!

Rob

Comment: `ssh -v` is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, did you make sure that:

- `PermitEmptyPassword` is set to `no`
- `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `yes`

And that, of course, you have set a password to your account.

Comment: driscan,                                                                                                                                 I did set those two variables to your recommendation and then restarted the sshd daemon.  The problem remains...